# Xcode: Share main storyboard between two targets

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I wouldn't do this at home, but I'm at work. (I.e. responses like "You shouldn't want to do that" won't wash.)

- **The goal**: to revert to a shared main storyboard for two targets.
- **The symptom**: outlets don't seem to connect.
- **Already tried**:

  - Deleting the app from the device
  - Doing a clean build
  - Poking around the storyboard XML (all looks as expected)

I inherited a project with two targets, each with its own storyboard. The targets share the *exact* same code. The second target's storyboard was cloned from the first target's. And its differences are minimal: mainly differing background images. *All* outlets go to the *same* ivar in code as do the corresponding outlets in the first storyboard. (AFAIK)

Now, the first naïve step is to merely tell the second target to use the first target's main storyboard. That happens in Targets > General > Deployment Info. (Or in the app's plist file, for hackers.) The appropriate storyboard *is* being copied in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

However when the app runs, before the Launch Screen disappears (i.e. loading home view) we crash with NSUnknownKeyException. For an outlet that seems to be properly connected in both storyboards. (To the same ivar of course.)

Now, expecting this to work right off the bat is asking too much. Obviously I have to handle those differing background images on a per-target basis. But I don't see any fundamental reason why the basic idea shouldn't be doable. Suggestions will be welcome as to how to proceed. (References to the Star Trek episode "Spock's Brain" will be funny only the first time.)

Comment: What is the unknown key?  As long as the class name is the same in both targets and all of the @IBOutlets are present it should work.

Comment: The unknown key is in fact the name of an ivar of the ViewController, and it is properly connected to the outlet in IB in both storyboards. So, as we all three apparently think, it should work. At least that gives me some encouragement, that I'm not trying something impossible. Will continue to hack.

Comment: For what it's worth, the key is "activityIndicator" which is the correct name of an instance variable that is connected via an @IBOutlet to the corresponding UI object in *both* Storyboards. (This outlet is first alphabetically, probably the first one that the runtime tries to connect.) I have deleted and recreated the connection to no avail. I have overridden setValue(_:forKey) and set a breakpoint, crash happens anyway, and no stopping at breakpoint. When I revert to the old Storyboard (identical in almost all respects) all is fine again. Mystery continues.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, and it does work. It's not an unreasonable approach if you have a reskinned app or one app that has minor differences like in-app purchases and another version that includes all the purchases for the price of the app.

It sounds like there's something more to your problem. Have you tried breaking on initWithCoder for the class that should have that outlet and verified that you're getting into it? There's no chance that the second target has a different class with the same name but different outlets and that's being used for the build or something like that?

Also, if you have the other code's storyboard in the project, have you made sure that the file targeting is correct on the two, so the correct storyboard is really being included if they both the same name? Likewise, for any files from the two projects that have the same class names.

I keep coming back to file targeting on this... It feels like something could be off there somewhere, so what you think is being used actually isn't.

I just tried it quickly here with a new project, two targets, deleted everything except the info.plist from the second, targeted all the files from the first target to the second and it worked fine--outlets were connected as expected.

Comment: Thank you Clarus, will advise on Monday. (No-work weekend!) Short story: storyboards have different names. When I remove the first storyboard from the second app's Copy Bundle Resources list I crash a lot earlier with file-not-found, so I believe I am using the correct storyboard file. Moof!

Comment: See response to Paulw11. Also tried deleting the old Storyboard; wasn't expecting a difference and did not see any. Definitely disinclined to continue parallel work (mostly autolayout) on the two Storyboards; equally disinclined to recreate from scratch the entire project with the one Storyboard and two targets. (Which should surely work.) P.S.: I appreciate your actually trying it before opining. No shade on Paulw11 above of course. But we've all experienced misguided "advice".